# laravel htaccess dont work in localhost server

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

I want to use htaccess when I developing project

```
  php artisan serve
```

but htaccess only work when my site is in production in real server 
dont work when I using

```
php artisan serve
```

Comment: did you create own htaccess file? show it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `.htaccess` is an Apache file, and `php artisan serve` launches internal web-server used for development. If you want your .htaccess file to have effect, you can install Apache locally and configure it. If you're on Mac, [Homebrew can do it for you easily](https://brew.sh). For windows, follow the installation guides on the [official website](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html).

Comment: did artisan have any config to do some redirect rule in that ?

Comment: No I don't think so.